# Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys

Tags: api, google, maps

Estou usando um código para navegar no Google Maps e apresentar as coordenadas na tela. No trecho do código é necessário informar uma credencial/key válida.
Eu inclui conforme solicitado, porém ainda apresenta um erro de "NoApiKeys".
Estou certo que minha chave(key) é válida pois uso em outras aplicações.

[image: tela de erro]

http://terrenos.deborahcorretora.com.br/obter_coord_posfix_copy_v1.html

Comment: Clicou no link do alert ? [Esse Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=keyless#api-key-and-billing-errors) Lá Tem uma mensagem referente a esse erro

Comment: Grato pela atenção. Pedro eu acredito que esteja tudo certo com a chave, pois já criei, configurei faturamento na conta do google e a chave está longe de atingir a cota. Alias a cota para consulta do mapa é ilimitada.